# Let $\mathcal{D}=\{(0,\frac{1}{n})\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$ Determine $\bigcup\mathcal{D}$ and $\bigcap\mathcal{D}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

> Let $\mathcal{D}=\{(0,\frac{1}{n})\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$ Determine $\bigcup\mathcal{D}$ and $\bigcap\mathcal{D}$.

I found this problem on an introductory set theory pdf, but they did not have any definitions for the notations $\bigcup\mathcal{D}$ and $\bigcap\mathcal{D}$. What might they be representing here?

Comment: Think it just means the union (for $\cup$) of all intervals of the form $(0,1/n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, i.e. $(0,1)\cup(0,1/2)\cup(0,1/3)\cup\dots$. Similarly for the intersection.

Comment: So $\mathcal{D}$ is the collection of open sets $(0, \frac{1}{n})$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\cup\mathcal{D}$ would be the union of all these open sets?

Comment: Yep -- that looks right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\FF}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\setb}[2]{\left\{ #1 \; \middle| \; #2 \right\}}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1  \right\}}$Generally for a family of sets $\FF$, we define those symbols as so:

$$\bigcup \FF = \bigcup_{F \in \FF} F \qquad \bigcap \FF = \bigcap_{F \in \FF} F$$

or, more precisely,

$$\bigcup \FF = \setb{x}{x \in F \text{ for some } F \in \FF}$$
$$\bigcap \FF = \setb{x}{x \in F \text{ for every } F \in \FF}$$

An example: let $\FF$ be the collection of sets

$$\Big\{ \set{1}, \set{1,2}, \set{1,2,3}, \set{1,2,3,4}, \cdots \Big\}$$

Then $\bigcup \FF = \Bbb Z^+$ and $\bigcap \FF = \set{1}$. That's because every positive integer will be in some $F \in \FF$ at some point, and $1$ is the only element in every $F \in \FF$.